# Filter Custom Post Type Loop by Year it was posted

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, while-loop, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type called eguide_landing.  I have created a custom archive page for that, where I loop through the CPT and display them, split into years.  This displays nicely.

I now want to create a widget on the sidebar that shows all the  years as hyperlinks, and on click, it reloads the page showing the CPT posts JUST from that year.  So if I clicked 2018, it would show all CPT posts in 2018 only.  I can't seem to work out how to create the code that pulls all the years, displays them as links, and then on click shows the archive page design but only with that year.

Here's the code for the archive page:

```
<?php
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'eguide_landing', 'paged' => $paged, 'posts_per_page' => 12 ) );


if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
    //Display the years as headers

    $current_year = get_the_time('Y');
    echo '<h2 class="current-year">'.$current_year.'</h2>';
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 

    $this_year = get_the_time('Y');
    if( $this_year!=$current_year ):
    $current_year = $this_year;
    echo '<h2 class="current-year">'.$current_year.'</h2>';
endif;?>  

    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
        <div class="eguide-single">
            <div class="left-columns">
                <div class="eguide-featured" style="background-image:url('<?php the_post_thumbnail_url();?>');"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="right-columns">
                <h2 style="margin-bottom:0;"><?php the_title();?></h2>
                <small><?php the_date();?></small>
                <?php the_excerpt();?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <?php endwhile;

// Render the Avada pagination

endif;

$pagination = fusion_pagination( $loop->max_num_pages, $loop );
echo $pagination;

wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make links that add ?year=2019 to the url. And then filter the result based on the 'year' argument:

```
 $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'eguide_landing', 'paged' => $paged, 'posts_per_page' => 12, 'year' => $_GET["year"]') );
```

And for the list of years, try one of these answers:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/145148/get-list-of-years-when-posts-have-been-published

Comment: Thanks. That doesn't seem to work for me.  When I add the ?year=2019 to the end of the URl, it redirects the entire URL to myurl.com/2019

Comment: turns out ?year= is already being used in WP.  changing it to ?theyear seems to stop it redirecting.

Comment: Other options would be to try the & symbol instead of ?.